# StatusBar for swipe activities

Tags: android, tabs

I want to add this kind of "Status bar" to my swipe activities but I don't have idea how to do it, I was looking for it but I haven't found it yet. Someone have any idea how to do it? I already have my swipe activities.

Here is an image example.

[image]

Comment: What did you try until now?

Comment: I haven´t tried anything, but I have some ideas. I added a layout  with two relativelayouts and include my viewpager in one of them that is where my swipe activities are and in the other I'm trying to add a tabhost and suppose that there it will be changing the statusbar. Sorry for my english btw, hope you understand.